# How can reduce the vertical space between 2 block on a tikzposter?

Tags: latex, tikz, overleaf

Hi all I would like to reduce the vertical space between block similarly to how its done to make the two column closer in the code below

```
\documentclass[a2paper,colspace=1pt]{tikzposter}
\usetheme{Board}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\node[above right,opacity=1.2,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt] at (bottomleft) {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{example-image-duck}};

\maketitle[titletotopverticalspace=-8cm] % See Section 4.1
\colorlet{blockbodybgcolor}{black}
\colorlet{blockbodyfgcolor}{white}
\colorlet{blocktitlefgcolor}{red}
\block{\textbf{Ultrastructural anylisis}}{}

\begin{columns}
\column{0.55} 
\block{\large Scientific Relevance}{
\small The overall \textcolor{red}{why is this outside?mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm}}

\column{0.45} \block{Ciao}{\lipsum[1]}
\end{columns}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like for the columns, there is a class option to control the vertical spacing:

```
\documentclass[a2paper,colspace=1pt,blockverticalspace=1pt]{tikzposter}
\usetheme{Board}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\node[above right,opacity=1.2,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt] at (bottomleft) {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{example-image-duck}};

\maketitle[titletotopverticalspace=-8cm] % See Section 4.1
\colorlet{blockbodybgcolor}{black}
\colorlet{blockbodyfgcolor}{white}
\colorlet{blocktitlefgcolor}{red}
\block{\textbf{Ultrastructural anylisis}}{}


\begin{columns}
\column{0.55} 
\block{\large Scientific Relevance}{
\small The overall \textcolor{red}{why is this outside?mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm}}

\column{0.45} \block{Ciao}{\lipsum[1]}
\end{columns}

\end{document}
```

[image]